# Insufficient Privileges on Change of Record Type

Tags: insufficient-privileges, privileges

I created a new opportunity record type for a specific user profile but I'm having privilege errors when the user is trying to use it. Here are some scenarios:

1. User creates opportunity using new record type - Fail
2. User creates opportunity using old record type - Pass
3. Using record from #2, user changes record type from old to new record type - Fail. It doesn't even register anything on the debug logs.
4. Admin creates opportunity using new record type - Pass
5. User accesses the record with the new record type created by the admin in #4 - Pass! User can view the record!

So the user can access a record with the new record type, but cannot create anything new with it. Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you enable the Record Type on the user's Profile? Do you have any validation rules or automation in place? What specific error do you receive?

Comment: Yes I enabled it on the profile. User can see it when creating new, or when changing the record type. Error is the standard "Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors." We have validation rules but I don't see anything failing there.

Comment: I would check for any sharing rules setup or automations which take away ownership or access

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. You guys are right we had an automation that on opportunity creation assigns a pricebook, which we restricted. I just had to share the relevant pricebook.